# Cancan super and admin abilities not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I have an app that has two roles, super and admin. Super can do everything and admin should be able to do everything except categories. I've implemented the following, but it is still allowing access to categories for admin:

```
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

  if user.has_role? :super
    can :manage, :all
  elsif user.has_role? :admin
    cannot :manage, :categories
    can :manage, :all
  end
end
```

If I change it to the below, it locks admin out of everything.

```
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

  if user.has_role? :super
    can :manage, :all
  elsif user.has_role? :admin
    can :manage, :all
    cannot :manage, :categories
  end
end
```

I have `load_and_authorize_resource` in all of my controllers, but still having no luck figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

The rules are finally concluded in an array.

In your first example, when you use `cannot`, such rule got deleted from the array. But then you define `can :manage, :all`, so the deleted ones recovered.

In the later example, `cannot` is put at last so the deletion actually have taken effect.